# Why does MarkLogic Enterprise cluster die when master instance is terminated?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm testing DR scenarios for 3 node cluster - ML8 and used CF template from https://developer.marklogic.com/products/aws link.

The issue I'm having is that when Master node is killed then whole cluster is offline.

Can someone explain to me why that is? Can we avoid that and what should we do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure all forest data that lives on the master is replicated to elsewhere, so that other hosts can take over, and all necessary databases can remain up. Investigate which databases are used by your application, and use [Forest-level Failover](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/cluster/failover#id_65543) to spread data across the cluster. Do this for internal databases like Security as well!

HTH!